# Programming with Oz on another text editor

Tags: text, editor, oz

I'm learning the Oz programming language at the university and we've used Emacs to run Oz code. I was wondering if it was possible to run Oz code on any other text editor like Notepad++ or even using an IDE like VS?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this plugin:
[Oz-plugin](https://github.com/2020saurav/oz-sublime)